# How do I calculate standard deviation and $\bar{x}$ if radius of circle is given?

Tags: standard-deviation, rounding-error

It is given radius of circle $r = 5cm$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 1mm$. How do I calculate $\bar{x}$ and standard deviation of calculated circle area?

I know these formulas but I dont know how to use them:

$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{N}^{i=1}x_i$

$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{N-1}}$

What is $N$ and $x_i$ in my case?

Comment: Do you mean that the _mean_ radius of the circle is $5$ cm? If $r=5$ (a constant) then the area has zero standard deviation, so that was probably not the intended interpretation. The formulas you found are for _sample_ mean and _sample_ s.d., which is not the only kind of mean or s.d. They probably don't apply here. Without knowing more about the probability distribution of the circle radius, however, I don't think we can accurately give the s.d. of its area.

Comment: @DavidK It is written that 5cm is radius of circle with standard deviation 1mm.

Comment: That's a self-contradictory statement. It might help if you could edit the question to give the complete story--why you are working on this problem, _exactly_ how it was specified, who specified it (and how, and why), anything else you can say about the context of the problem, because as you have presented it so far it doesn't make any sense. I can't give any guarantee that this will help; I have no way to know if you even have sufficient information to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The area is $A=\pi r^2$

so $\mathbb E[A] = \pi\mathbb E[r^2] =\pi((E[r])^2+\sigma_r^2) = 25.01 \pi \approx 78.5712 \text{ cm}^2$

The standard deviation of $A$ depends on the distribution of $r$.  You could calculate it as $\sqrt{\mathbb E[A^2]-(E[A])^2} = \pi \sqrt{\mathbb E[r^4]-(E[r^2])^2}$. For example

- $r$ might take the values $4.9$ and $5.1\text{ cm}$ with equal probability, in which case the standard deviation of $A$ would be $\pi \approx 3.1416 \text{ cm}^2$.  I suspect that this may be the minimum possible value
- $r$ might be distributed with zero skewness and excess kurtosis (like a normal distribution, though here $r$ cannot be negative) in which case the standard deviation of $A$ would be marginally greater at about $3.1419 \text{ cm}^2$

Answer (score 0):

When adding or subtracting values, their absolute errors sum up, while for multiplication and division the *relative* errors sum up (what should be mentioned in [error analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_(mathematics))).

The given $\sigma$ is a not the *plus/minus* shown with meassured values, but with the unit $mm$ an absolute value. A relative data would be $\displaystyle \frac{1mm}{5cm}$ or $\sigma_{rel}=0,02$ -- *note*: for the radius.

To get the area of a circle its radius must be sqared, what doubles the relative error of the circles area $A$. Thus its $\sigma_{rel}=0,04$. Or absolute $\displaystyle \sigma_{A}=\pi5^2{cm}^2\frac{2}{50}=\pi$ ${cm}^2$.

Answer (score -1):

My $2$ cents

$\bar r= 5 \text{ mm}$

$\sigma_r = 1 \text{ mm}$

means $68 \%$ of the circles have radii $r$ such that $4 \text{ mm} \leq r \leq 6 \text{ mm}$ and $16\%$ of the circles have $r < 4 \text{ mm} $ and $16\%$ of the circles have $r > 6 \text{ mm}$

From my recent foray into stats ...

The *means* of $2$ independent random variables can be *added*: $\bar W = \bar Y + \bar Z$ (so $5 + 5 = 10$)

The *variance* of the "combination" ($W$) is:
$\sigma_W^2 = \sigma_X ^2 + \sigma_Y ^2$

This however is *squaring/multiplication* (area), but then ...
multiplication is *repeated addition*.